# Comment traduire « clear and present danger to the nation » : choix des adjectifs et préposition ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, prépositions, adjectifs

> [...] He must go.  He is a **clear and present danger** to the nation that
> we all love.  Since the presidential election in November – an
> election the President lost – he has repeatedly held about – lied
> about the outcome, sowed self-serving doubt about democracy and
> unconstitutionally sought to influence state officials to repeal
> reality.  And, then, came that day of fire we all experienced.
>
> Nancy Pelosi, *[Floor Speech](https://www.speaker.gov/newsroom/11321-0) on H.Res. 24, Impeaching Donald John
> Trump, President of the United States, for Incitement of Insurrection*
> (extrait, je souligne)

Dans [un article](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/etats-unis/2021-01-13/assaut-du-capitole/le-congres-vote-la-mise-en-accusation-de-trump-pour-avoir-incite-a-la-violence.php) basé sur une dépêche de l'AFP, on traduit ça par « il est un **danger évident et immédiat contre** la nation que nous aimons tous », que je trouve bizarre vu la préposition [*contre*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/contre). Sur [Termium](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=CLEAR%20PRESENT%20DANGER%20TEST&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) on dit « danger clair et présent » mais il s'agit d'un *test* dans le contexte d'un arrêt canadien ; en fait la [traduction](https://scc-csc.lexum.com/scc-csc/scc-csc/fr/item/695/index.do) de cet arrêt emploie « danger clair et actuel ». Par ailleurs techniquement ce test a été [remplacé](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clear_and_present_danger) aux États-Unis par celui du « imminent lawless action » ([historique](https://www.law.cornell.edu/constitution-conan/amendment-1/subsequent-punishment-clear-and-present-danger-and-other-tests)).

Quels deux adjectifs choisit-on le plus fréquemment/adéquatement afin de qualifier le *danger* en question dans « clear and present danger » ; quelle préposition emploie-t-on pour relier le groupe nominal à « to the nation we all love » ; pourquoi ?

Comment: Je dirais "Il est un danger clair et immédiat pour la nation que nous aimons tous". 'Contre' me parait incorrect dans la traduction.

Comment: Je ne comprends pas pourquoi "contre" ne conviendrait pas. Il me semble que le sens II.A.1. de la définition en référence correspond bien à la phrase présente. Cela dit, "pour" semble également convenir (sens II.C.2. de [pour](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pour)).

Comment: @mouviciel Pour moi c'est complètement inusité même si sémantiquement ça convient, quoique « Le plus souvent les verbes ou les subst. qui précèdent contre, expriment l'attaque, l'hostilité, l'argumentation. ... Subst. + contre : attaque, attentat, campagne, colère, combat, force, fureur, guerre, haine, indignation, lutte, (prendre) parti, protestation, réaction, révolte, rancune, argument, débat, preuve. ... Dans une proportion moindre, ils expriment l'idée de défense, de résistance. ... assurance, (être, mettre) en garde, plainte, précaution, protection, refuge, etc. » (TLFi)

Answer (score 1):

On peut proposer :

- *un danger **grave** et **imminent*** pour la nation/la patrie/les institutions.
- *un danger **manifeste** et **imminent***...
- *un danger **avéré** et **imminent***...

La première formule existe déjà en [droit français](https://www.fonction-publique.gouv.fr/files/files/carrieres_et_parcours_professionnel/sante_securite_travail_fp/guide-juridique-circulaire-D82-453.pdf) (droit du travail).

> La notion de danger grave et imminent doit être entendue, par référence à la jurisprudence sociale, comme étant une menace directe pour la vie ou la santé du fonctionnaire ou de l'agent, c'est-à-dire une situation de fait pouvant provoquer un dommage à l'intégrité physique ou à la santé de la personne.
> ...
> • Le danger en cause doit donc être grave. Selon la circulaire de la direction générale du travail du 25 mars 1993, un danger grave est « un danger susceptible de produire un accident ou une maladie entraînant la mort ou paraissant devoir entraîner une incapacité permanente ou temporaire prolongée ». « La gravité a donc des conséquences définitives ou en tout cas longues à effacer et importantes, au-delà d’un simple inconfort.
> ...
> • Le caractère imminent du danger se caractérise par le fait que le danger est
> « susceptible de se réaliser brutalement dans un délai rapproché. L’imminence du danger suppose qu’il ne se soit pas encore réalisé mais qu’il soit susceptible de se concrétiser dans un bref délai... »

Bien que *danger grave et imminent* s'applique dans cette définition à un ou plusieurs individus alors que *clear and present danger* s'applique, dans sa [définition juridique](https://www.merriam-webster.com/legal/clear%20and%20present%20danger) à la collectivité toute entière, je pense qu'il y a suffisamment de points communs pour la retenir. Il s'agit dans les deux cas de prendre des mesures exceptionnelles, extraordinaires, qui vont à l'encontre des règles habituelles, face à ce qu'on peut rapprocher d'un *cas de force majeure*.

Sinon, *manifeste* et *avéré* correspondent bien, il me semble, à ce que l'anglais *clear* (*easily visible, free from ambiguity, doubt*) signifie.

*Immédiat* est très proche d'*imminent* mais ce dernier insiste sur la composante temporelle que l'on trouve dans *present* alors qu'immédiat peut aussi s'appliquer à l'espace. On peut quand même noter que la traduction du titre du film ***Clear and Present Danger*** est [**Danger immédiat**](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danger_imm%C3%A9diat_(film)).

Pour ce qui concerne la préposition, je pense comme vc-74 que *pour* est plus indiqué :

> *Pour* la nation, c'est un danger.

On lit cependant parfois *un danger contre quelque chose ou quelqu'un* mais une recherche Google sur *danger contre la nation* ne trouve curieusement que des références provenant de pages du Congo, du Cameroun, d'Algérie, de Tunisie et du Sénégal qui laissent penser qu'il s'agit peut-être d'un régionalisme, ou du moins d'une forme plus rare en France, ce que confirme Google Books :

[image]

Comment: En ce qui concerne la première formule, c'est précisément parce qu'elle a une définition et un champ d'application spécifiques dans le jargon juridique que j'éviterais de l'employer hors de ce contexte particulier. À moins que l'original en anglais soit aussi du jargon juridique couvrant la même notion.

Comment: @mouviciel La notion existe bien juridiquement [en anglais](https://www.merriam-webster.com/legal/clear%20and%20present%20danger). La différence est qu'elle s'applique à la collectivité alors que celle du français s'applique à un ou plusieurs individus. Je ne pense pas que cette différence suffise à la disqualifier.

Comment: "serious and imminent" correspond bien en effet.

Comment: Merci, pour une fois qu'on a le même titre de film! Ouais pour le droit français, ça ressemble à une qualification de la menace de préjudice, ça rappelle aussi des critères de la causalité. J'aime bien manifeste et imminent. C'est le danger de réalisation de ce qui est encouragé par la parole/gestes dont on traite. Parfois ça pourrait simplement justifier la restriction de la liberté d'expression associée à une infraction. Mais oui, avec le contexte ça connote certainement le péril en la demeure, quoique ça s'incrive dans l'évocation d'un standard atteint qui justifie la procédure. Pas facile.